# Order of execution with Haskell's `mapM`

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad, traversable

Consider the following Haskell statement:

```
mapM print ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Indeed, this prints "1", "2", and "3" in order.

**Question:** How do you know that `mapM` will *first* print "1", and *then* print "2", and *finally* print "3". Is there any guarantee that it will do this? Or is it a coincidence of how it is implemented deep within GHC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you evaluate `mapM print ["1", "2", "3"]` by expanding the definition of `mapM` you will arrive at (ignoring some irrelevant details)

```
print "1" >> print "2" >> print "3"
```

You can think of `print` and `>>` as abstract constructors of IO actions that cannot be evaluated any further, just as a data constructor like `Just` cannot be evaluated any further.

The interpretation of `print s` is the action of printing `s`, and the interpretation of `a >> b` is the action that first performs `a` and then performs `b`. So, the interpretation of

```
mapM print ["1", "2", "3"] = print "1" >> print "2" >> print "3"
```

is to first print 1, then print 2, and finally print 3.

How this is *actually* implemented in GHC is entirely a different matter which you shouldn't worry about for a long time.

Comment: I prefer to break it down as far as `print = putStrLn . show`. You could go a bit further, but that at least explains the role of `Show`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no guarantee on the order of the evaluation but there is a guarantee on the order of the effects. For more information see [this answer that discusses `forM`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754668/667648)

> You need to learn to make the following, tricky distinction:
>
> 1. The order of evaluation
> 2. The order of effects (a.k.a. "actions")
>
> What
>   forM, sequence and similar functions promise is that the effects will
>   be ordered from left to right. So for example, the following is
>   guaranteed to print characters in the same order that they occur in
>   the string...

[Note](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:forM): "`forM` is `mapM` with its arguments flipped. For a version that ignores the results see `forM_`."

Comment: So in my example I *am* guaranteed that "1" will print before "2" will print before "3" since "1" is left of "2" is left of "3" and printing is an effect?

Comment: Yes. The order that they are printed is preserved.

Comment: Good answer you've linked to. What I don't understand is, _why didn't you upvote it_?

Answer (score 4):

Preliminary note: The answers by Reid Barton and Dair are entirely correct and fully cover your practical concerns. I mention that because partway through this answer one might have the impression that it contradicts them, which is not the case, as will be clear by the time we get to the end. That being clear, it is time to indulge in some language lawyering.

> Is there any guarantee that [`mapM print`] will [print the list elements in order]?

Yes, there is, as explained by the other answers. Here, I will discuss what might justify this guarantee.

In this day and age, `mapM` is, by default, merely `traverse` specialised to monads:

```
traverse
  :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
mapM
  :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

That being so, in what follows I will be primarily concerned with `traverse`, and how our expectations about the sequencing of effects relate to the `Traversable` class.

As far as the production of effects is concerned, `traverse` generates an `Applicative` effect for each value in the traversed container and combines all such effects through the relevant `Applicative` instance. This second part is clearly reflected by the type of `sequenceA`, through which the applicative context is, so to say, factored out of the container:

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)

-- sequenceA and traverse are interrelated by:
traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f
sequenceA = traverse id
```

[The `Traversable` instance for lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#line-184), for example, is:

```
instance Traversable [] where
    {-# INLINE traverse #-} -- so that traverse can fuse
    traverse f = List.foldr cons_f (pure [])
      where cons_f x ys = (:) <$> f x <*> ys
```

It is plain to see that the combining, and therefore the sequencing, of effects is done through `(<*>)`, so let's focus on it for a moment. Picking the `IO` applicative functor as an illustrative example, we can see `(<*>)` sequencing effects from left to right:

```
GHCi> -- Superfluous parentheses added for emphasis.
GHCi> ((putStrLn "Type something:" >> return reverse) <*> getLine) >>= putStrLn
Type something:
Whatever
revetahW
```

`(<*>)`, however, sequences effects from left-to-right [by convention, and not for any inherent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14259453/2751851). As witnessed by [the `Backwards` wrapper from *transformers*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html), it is, in principle, always possible to implement `(<*>)` with right-to-left sequencing and still get a lawful `Applicative` instance. Without using the wrapper, it is also possible to take advantage of `(<**>)` from `Control.Applicative` to invert the sequencing:

```
(<**>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
```

```
GHCi> import Control.Applicative
GHCi> (getLine <**> (putStrLn "Type something:" >> return reverse)) >>= putStrLn
Whatever
Type something:
revetahW
```

Given that it is so easy to flip the sequencing of `Applicative` effects, one might wonder whether this trick might transfer to `Traversable`. For instance, let's say we implement...

```
esrevart :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
```

... so that it is just like `traverse` for lists save for using `Backwards` or `(<**>)` to flip the sequencing of effects (I will leave that as an exercise for the reader). Would `esrevart` be a legal implementation of `traverse`? While we might figure it out by trying to prove the [identity and composition laws of `Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html) hold, that is actually not necessary: given that `Backwards f` for any applicative `f` is also applicative, an `esrevart` patterned after any lawful `traverse` will also follow the `Traversable` laws. [The `Reverse` wrapper](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Reverse.html), also part of *transformers*, offers a general implementation of this reversal.

We have thus concluded that there can be legal `Traversable` instances that differ in the sequencing of effects. In particular, a list `traverse` that sequences effects from tail to head is conceivable. That doesn't make the possibility any less strange, though. To avoid utter bewilderment, `Traversable` instances are conventionally implemented with plain `(<*>)` and following the natural order in which the constructors are used to build the traversable container, which in the case of lists amounts to the expected head-to-tail sequencing of effects. One place where this convention shows up is in the automatic generation of instances by [the `DeriveTraversable` extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/DeriveFunctor#DeriveTraversable).

A final, historical note. Couching this discussion, which is ultimately about `mapM`, in terms of the `Traversable` class would be a move of dubious relevance in a not so distant past. `mapM` was effectively subsumed by `traverse` only last year, but it has existed for much longer. For instance, the [Haskell Report 1.3](https://wiki.haskell.org/Language_and_library_specification#Historic_development_of_Haskell) from 1996, years before `Applicative` and `Traversable` came into being (not even `ap` is there, in fact), provides the following specification for `mapM`:

```
accumulate        :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
accumulate        =  foldr mcons (return [])
                     where mcons p q = p >>= \x -> q >>= \y -> return (x:y)

mapM              :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM f as         =  accumulate (map f as)
```

The sequencing of effects, here enforced through `(>>=)`, is left-to-right, for no other reason than it being the sensible thing to do.

P.S.: It is worth emphasising that, while it is possible to write a right-to-left `mapM` in terms of the `Monad` operations (in the Report 1.3 implementation quoted here, for instance, it merely requires exchanging `p` and `q` in the right-hand side of `mcons`), there is no such thing as a general `Backwards` for monads. Since `f` in `x >>= f` is a `Monad m => a -> m b` function which creates effects from values, the effects associated with `f` depend on `x`. As a consequence, a simple inversion of sequencing like that possible with `(<*>)` is not even guaranteed to be meaningful, let alone lawful.

Comment: Implementing the `Traversable` instance for `Data.Functor.Reverse` is not such a trivial exercise, and relies essentially on `Backwards`. It may bear mention that there can be nothing like `Backwards` for the `Monad` class.

Comment: @dfeuer [1] Indeed. (What makes it a little trickier is that in the general `(Traversable f) => Traversable (Reverse f)` case you can't play with neither `(<*>)` nor the structure of the (unknown) `Traversable`.) By the way, I will add a link to `Data.Functor.Reverse`. [2] That is definitely worth mentioning; I will add a note about it. (I had chosen not to include an extra paragraph about `Monad`, and that remark was supposed to be made somewhere in it.) Useful reminders, thanks.